# When I use "n--" instead of "n-1" why do I get stackoverflow error?

Tags: java, recursion

In this code which is a program to print elements 1 to 5 recursively, when I use `n--` instead of `n-1`, I am getting a stack overflow error.
whereas when `n-1` is used the code worked perfectly.
shouldn't `n--` and `n-1` work the same in this code?

```
    //when using n--

    class PrintElements1to5
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            recursivePrint(5);
        }
    
        static void recursivePrint(int n)
        {
            if(n<1)
                return;
            recursivePrint(n--);  
            System.out.print(n+" ");
        }
    }
```

output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

```
    //when using n=n-1
    class PrintElements1to5
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            recursivePrint(5);
        }
    
        static void recursivePrint(int n)
        {
            if(n<1)
                return;
            recursivePrint(n-1);
            System.out.print(n+" ");
        }
    }
```

output:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`n--` returns the value of `n` first, then decrement `n`. So in your case, it becomes an infinite loop because `n` is never changing. You can use `--n` instead which decrement `n` first, then returns the value of `n`. Let's take a simpler example.

```
int x = 3;
System.out.println(x - 1); // prints 2, x is still 3
System.out.println(x--);   // prints 3, x becomes 2
System.out.println(--x);   // prints 1, x becomes 1
```